# What types of threats are RESTful services susceptible to?

Tags: security, validation, rest, spring-mvc, jersey

What types of vulnerabilities or threats are RESTful web services susceptible to?

I work on a project which exposes a lot of these services however there is a lack of any validation or security.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a short non-exhaustive list, there are a few things that you should keep in mind:

- **Do not abuse GET request when working with sensitive data**
  When passing sensitive data, always use POST/PUT/DELETE with secure connection (https). Of course, proper SSL certification and configuration is needed to ensure the communication cannot be decoded by third parties.
- **For RESTful authentication, avoid passing credentials on each request.**
- **Do not get tempted to use HTTP error codes for authentication errors**
  When authenticating, try to make the service behave in the same way regardless if there is authentication failure or success. Always return the same HTTP error code (200 OK, but with a different body depending on the authentication result). This may confuse potential attacker of whether his technique is working or if he had found a weak spot, they must now learn how to interpret the response body of your API. Giving too much information from the HTTP response will help them orient themselves faster. Leave HTTP error codes for their true purpose -- to inform of HTTP communication issues. This is also good for developers who would integrate with the API, as the behavior is less ambiguous.
- **Allow limited attempts to authenticate**
  Reject connection from clients who perform too much unsuccessful authentication attempts for a limited amount of time. Some systems would prevent you from authenticating again within 10 or 30 minutes if you were unable to log-in after a small number of attempts. This could reduce the risk of a DDoS attack, and could significantly cripple any brute-force password guess attempts.
- **Password validation time matters**
  If using password encryption on the sever side, use such comparison algorithms between the incoming password and the one stored in the server, so that it will take near-equal time to compare passwords regardless of them being correct or not. Add custom timeouts when necessary. This could prevent a timed attack - usually wrong passwords are rejected faster by most algorithms and a hacker may use the response time differences to determine if s/he is getting closer to guessing the password. Combined with limited authentication attempts, this can be prevented.
- **CORS**
  By using CORS you also limit the allowed users of your api when ran into the browser. This could be a serious improvement security wise, as an attacker would not be capable of attacking your RESTful API directly from their machines, but rather they have to find ways of bypassing CORS. The latter could further be prevented by using strict enough CORS rules and having good security on the servers hosting the allowed CORS urls, so that an attacker may not compromise a CORS-allowed machine that can access the API directly.

Of course, there are other things that must be kept in mind, these are the most important I can come up with now.

You should also know, that the request/response are still visible in the Network tab of Firebug (or whatever browser debugger you are using), or any attached traffic listener, so anyone on a web page calling the REST service can at least see the url and the data for get/requests and the response.

Pass and return data that is needed to be visualized and for the page/app to work correctly, never return sensitive info like passwords or user sensitive data.

Like many services, RESTful  services can be a subject of DDoS attack, still the latter aims at shutting down the service rather than compromising data or accomplish an authorization/authentication breach.